# Animating a view in a fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, android-animation

I'm trying to animate an imageview in a fragment. I tried by creating a XML animation and also by doing it in Kotlin, but everytime I run the app, it crashes.

```
class WelcomeFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentWelcomeBinding
private lateinit var zoomAnimation: Animation
private lateinit var turnedOffStar: ImageView

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                         savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_welcome,
        container,
        false
    )
    binding.turnedOffStarButton.setOnClickListener { v: View ->

    }
    scaler()
    zoomAnimation()
    return binding.root
}


private fun zoomAnimation() {
    zoomAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity?.baseContext,R.anim.zoom_undonestar)
    turnedOffStar.startAnimation(zoomAnimation)
}

private fun scaler() {
    val scaleX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 0.3F)
    val scaleY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 0.3F)
    val animator: ObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(turnedOffStar, scaleX, scaleY)
    animator.repeatCount = INFINITE
    animator.repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.REVERSE
    animator.start()
}
```

}

First I tried using the fun zoomAnimation, after the fun scaler. Does this has something to do with the fact that I'm animating inside a fragment? Because I already did an animation inside an activity, and it worked fine.

Comment: I think the view you are using in `scaler` function (turnedOffStar) is the one from kotlin android extensions. Those one will not work inside `onCreateView()` like you are using it now and you should use one from bindings. But also the animation should be started from `onStart`/`onResume` instead

Comment: @V-master If I start the animation in onStart/onResume, everytime I change the app and go back to mine, the animation stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ImageView `turnedOffStar` is not initialized anywhere. Since you are already using data binding, you should reference your views using it. So, you should reference your image view something like: `binding.turnedOffStar.startAnimation()`

Comment: Thanks! I solved it by adding `turnedOffStar = binding.turnedOffStarButton`

Comment: Im glad i helped, but you don't to declare variable `turnedOffStar`. You can use `binding.turnedOffStar` where ever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you add your stack trace(Log) along with your code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm starting in android development now and I'm still not used to it/to some others good practices, but thanks for the tip!